# How to Inflate Custom XML Layout into Custom ItemDecoration?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, item-decoration

I wish to add a Custom ItemDecoration in my RecyclerView that is a layout defined in a XML file.

So far I was able to inflate the XML and position using canvas.translate (yet, without understanding everything).

Currently I have this code to draw:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {

        for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)

            val left = child.marginLeft
            val top = child.top

            context?.let {

                //Inflate the Layout and set the Values (a text in this case)
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(it).inflate(R.layout.my_decoration_layout, parent, false)
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
                textView.text = "This is an ItemDecoration"

                //Calculate the Size. Im using "hardcoded" values, but this does not seems to change how the View is rendered
                view.measure(1000,1000)
                view.layout(0, 0, 1000, 1000)

                //Draw. I had to translate the canvas to apply the offset for each "ViewHolder"
                canvas.save()
                canvas.translate(left.toFloat(), top.toFloat())
                view.draw(canvas)
                canvas.restore()
            }


        }
    }
```

The XML is (note the background colors to see the Rendered Area):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

With this, I could inflate and position my XML between each ViewHolder, but I still have two big issues:

1. My TextView is drawed over the ViewHolder, so I get here an overlap.
   Would be great if this "Draw" operation pushes the ViewHolder.
2. Even my custom XML layout has it's width as "match_parent", it only wraps the text view.

If possible, Id like to know which exactly what "measure" and "layout" means and how it affect my View "area".
And how to prevent the overlap.

I "solved" the Overlap issue drawing a Text on the Canvas, using

```
Paint().apply {
    color = Color.BLACK
    style = Paint.Style.FILL
    textSize = 40f

    canvas.drawText(year.toString(), left.toFloat(), top.toFloat(), this)
}
```

But since my layout is a bit more complex, would be nice to understand how to do it with XML layouts.

Thanks